# Language-learning site for correcting single sentences

Tags: webapp-rec

There are several sites that allow one to submit essays for correction by natives, often in exchange for correcting texts in one's own mother-tongue. Is there such a site where I can get single sentences checked and corrected?

The language in question is German, but I'm interested in any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their site, [AskLingo](http://asklingo.com/) does this.

> - Ask for translation of basic phrases